# Need Help Solving A Riddle

Tags: riddle

Riddle: Hand on Top

**Hint 1:**

> The answer is a phrase

**Hint 2:**

> It's known as 3434 and 4343 means the opposite

**Hint 3:**

> It's was used in WWII

**Hint 4:**

> The first letter of each word is capitalized and the end letter can be as well

My friend ask me the question, not sure on the source.